# Google Cloud Storage: Where do I get per-bucket statistics

Tags: statistics, google-cloud-storage

I would like to pull stats on a per bucket basis. Is this possible?

Comment: Graphs of object count, object size, requests, and more over time for each Google Cloud Storage bucket can be seen through Stackdriver at https://app.google.stackdriver.com/services/gcs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(updated answer 2014/09/23 to reflect changes in the gsutil command)

`gsutil du` displays the amount of space (in bytes) being used by the
objects in hierarchy under a given URL.

- `s` gives a summary total instead of the size of each object.
- `h` prints human readable sizes instead of bytes.

So:

```
$ gsutil du -sh gs://BUCKET_NAME
261.46 GB   gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

... gives the total size of objects in the bucket. However, it is calculated on request and can take a long time for buckets with many objects.

For production use, enable [Access Logs & Storage Data](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs). The storage data logs will give you the average size in bytes/per hour for each bucket for the previous day.

The access logs give [details](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs#reviewing) about each request to your logged buckets.

There is also [information on loading](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs#downloading) the logs into [BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/) for analysis.

Comment: I've tried this command, but it does not return the number of objects. Here is the output:
gsutil ls -L -b gs://MYBUCKET
gs://MYBUCKT/ :
 Storage class:   DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY
 Location constraint:  US
 Versioning enabled:  None
 Logging configuration:  None
 Website configuration:  None
 CORS configuration:   None
 Lifecycle configuration: None

Comment: Daniel, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Delivery of access logs can be enabled per bucket as [documented](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesslogs). When bucket logging is enabled, log files are written to the user defined logging bucket on a best effort hourly basis. You can pull log files from there and parse and count with your tool of choice. If you don't want to run analytics yourself on the raw logs you can use a service such as [Qloudstat](https://qloudstat.com). (Disclaimer: I work for the company behind.)

Comment: The link to your service doesn't work, @david-kocher

Comment: Unfortunately Qloudstat has been discontinued.